# How to run .mdf database from LAN?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a C# (.NET Framework 4.5 - MVS 2015) project which has a Service-based Database with a local generated .mdf file. My Microsoft SQL Server that I use has this version: 13.0.1601.5.
Everything works fine on the server PC. I share in LAN the application with the .mdf files, but the clients from the same LAN can't open the application. It seems that the connection with the DB is bad.

My connection string is formed like this:

```
public static string attachedDbFile = "AttachDbFilename=" + currentWorkinglocation + "NCI_DB.MDF;";

public SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;" + attachedDbFile + "Integrated Security=True");
```

What am I missing, please?

**Later Edit:**

After following the steps provided by you guys:

My Data Source is Microsoft SQL Server now (and not MSQL Server Db file). I have attached the .mdf file to a database from my server (in MSQL Server Management Studio), the "Allow remote connection option" is checked and I have changed the connection string to:

```
public SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=myDbName;Integrated Security=True");
```

Now, the application works on my local host (the PC that has the sql server installed) without the need of the .mdf file. It's ok.

But if the clients try to access the application from LAN, from my shared location, the app .exe crashes once again with this error message:

[image]

Did I missed something?

**SOLUTION:**
After following some pointers from our colleagues and after investigating further the problem the solution is:
- install sql server 2017 (full version ! - not express edition)
- install microsoft sql server management studio
- attach mdf to a database
- configure an account with rights for that database
- update the connection string according to this:

```
public SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ip,port(1433-default);Initial Catalog=db_name;User ID=user;Password=pwd");
```

Comment: `(LocalDB)` refers to the local instance of SQL Server. If your clients do not all have LocalDB installed as well, this won't work. Furthermore, if you intended the database to be *shared* among clients, this won't work at all: you'll have to install SQL Server (Express) on its own machine. Only one SQL Server instance can have a database attached at any given time.

Comment: I've red that maybe I could redirect the clients to my local DB by referring them to my IP? Isn't there any solution?

Comment: A LocalDB instance is not accessible from the network. If you want to run the database locally while exposing it to external clients, you can, but you'll have to install the (equally free) SQL Server Express.

Comment: You can connect by simply changing (LocalDB) to a remote PC with SQL installed.  The instance name my need to get changed (MSSQLLocalDB) if the remote PC database is using a different instance.  You are using "Integrated Security=True" which means the database is using Windows Credentials.  So the local and remote PC must have the same UserGroup, the database credentials must use the group, and the User Account must be in the group on both local and remote PC.Jereon is wrong. Installing SQL Express just automatically sets up the credentials I described and it not required if accessing from c#.

Comment: @jdweng: A LocalDB instance (not to be confused with the special `(local)` alias for the local host) is set up and configured to listen only on a local named pipe and will not accept connections from other computers. If you can show otherwise, please write up an answer with detailed instructions, I'd be interested in it. Of course you can install SQL Server on any machine that you like, but using LocalDB confines you to the local machine -- at least according to anything I've ever read and seen.

Comment: The SQL Service is setup to listen on port 8080 so the SQL Server will listen to any connection using it URL name (like (MSSQLLocalDB) either from local or remote PC.  Windows will block an outside connections if the credential isn't allowed.  Also the database (mdf file) has to be attached to the Server for the remote PC to access the database.  I always recommend NOT using the mdf name in the connection string.  When the mdf file name is used credential issues occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL server only supports database files on local disks (or more exotic links than LANs, such as iSCSI, etc). If you want to share access to a database across a local network, it's time to stand up a SQL Server instance that will own the file and then connect to that SQL Server client/server. Stop trying to access it as a *file* across the network.

Comment: What do you mean by "stand up a SQL Server instance that will own the file"? How could I do this? Any additional information please?

Comment: @Marko - you already have at least one instance of SQL Server installed on your *own* machine. However, that may not be the most *appropriate* location to act as the server for all of the other machines. So you may need to install an instance on a more appropriate machine. Then you attach the MDF file (plenty of help found online for attaching files to servers), and then your connection string uses `Database` rather than `AttachDbFileName` (and `Data Source`, a.k.a. `Server` identifiers the server instance you've selected)

Comment: @Marko - but bear in mind that your local instance is likely SQL Server express, and by default that's not open to remote connections. Again, plenty of help online if you *need* to do that.

Comment: I see. So the steps would be: 1. check if my local instance is SQL Server express (which I doubt because I see in control panel that it states simply MSQL Server 2016 LocalDB); 2. attach .mdf file to MSQL Server 2016 which I use (I think I will need MSQL Server Management Studio for this); 3. change the connection string according to the new approach. Is this right?

Comment: Damien : Make it very clear you CAN access a database through the SQL Server on a remote PC.  Installing SQL Server on a PC allows a connecting to a Remote server.   Also the drivers in the Net Library (SQL Client Class) allows connections to remote SQL Servers.

Comment: Damien, I've managed to solve it after a couple of hours of struggle. Thank you for your indications!